# При выводе значения дочернего элемента выводит undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("partner");
alert(elem.firstChild.innerHTML);
alert(elem.lastChild.innerHTML);
```

```html
<ul id="partner">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>empty</li>
  <li>empty</li>
  <li>last text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(elem.firstChild.nodeName + ", " + elem.firstChild.innerHTML);
```

Сравните:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("partner");
alert(elem.firstChild.innerHTML);
alert(elem.lastChild.innerHTML);
```

```html
<ul id="partner"><li>text</li><li>empty</li><li>empty</li><li>last text</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

`alert(elem.firstElementChild.innerHTML);`